AgGrid Excel Exports processCellCallback vs valueGetter
In our application we make use of Luxon DateTime rather than JS Date.
This means that all of our date columns need to be formatted using:
param.data.fieldName?.toISO({ includeOffset: false }) || ''

My question is, should I be doing this in processCellCallback or valueGetter?
I don't see any documentation about processCellCallback on the AG-Grid doc/api pages, so I am not sure if one has an advantage over the other.

Here is the documentation for processCellCallback. valueGetter is used to get the value to display in the grid whereas processCellCallback is used to get the value to display in the export.

Interesting, thanks for the link. If you search for 'processCellCallback' on the Docs page, you get:
No Results for "processCellCallback"
